# Ignore ascii characters on Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

How could I ignore ascii characters on Elasticsearch ? 
I read http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html but don't really now how to perform that.

I'm using the PHP package.

```
public function createIndex()
{
    $indexParams['index'] = $this->data['index'];

    $mapping = [
        '_source'    => [
            'enabled' => true
        ],
        'properties' => [
            'history.name'  => [
                'type'  => 'string',
                '_boost' => 0.2
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $settings = [
        "analysis" => [
            "analyzer" => [
                "default" => [
                    "tokenizer" => "standard",
                    "filter" => ["standard", "asciifolding"]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $indexParams['body']['mappings'][$this->data['type']] = $mapping;
    $indexParams['body']['settings'][$this->data['type']] = $settings;

    $this->es->client->indices()->create($indexParams);
}
```

But this still doesn't ignore accented characters.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few corrections and suggestions:

- I prefer to set explicit analyzers, rather than change the default.  Fewer surprises in the future.  So in your example, I explicitly set `analyzer: ascii_folding`
- I then change the analyzer name from `default` to `ascii_folding`
- And finally, settings are per-index, not per-type.  The JSON structure is:

  ```
  {
    "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {}
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "my_type" : {}
    }
  }
  ```

Edit:  Replaced the old example with a tested and working piece of code.  Hardcoded a few values (index, type, etc) but otherwise identical.  It returns the doc as a hit...there must be something else wrong with your query.

```
$indexParams['index'] = 'test';
$mapping = [
    '_source'    => [
        'enabled' => true
    ],
    'properties' => [
        'history.name'  => [
            'type'  => 'string',
            '_boost' => 0.2,
            'analyzer' => 'ascii_folding'
        ]
    ]
];
$settings = [
    "analysis" => [
        "analyzer" => [
            "ascii_folding" => [
                "tokenizer" => "standard",
                "filter" => ["standard", "asciifolding"]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$indexParams['body']['mappings']['test'] = $mapping;
$indexParams['body']['settings'] = $settings;

// create index and wait for yellow
$client->indices()->create($indexParams);
$client->cluster()->health(['wait_for_status' => 'yellow']);


//Index your document, refresh to make it visible
$params = [
    'index' => 'test',
    'type' => 'test',
    'id' => 1,
    'body' => [
        'history.name' => 'Nicôlàs Wîdàrt'
    ]
];
$client->index($params);
$client->indices()->refresh();

// Now search for it
$params = [
    'index' => 'test',
    'type' => 'test',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'history.name' => 'Nicolas'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$results = $client->search($params);
print_r($results);
```

Which yields the single doc back as a value:

```
Array
(
    [took] => 3
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 5
            [successful] => 5
            [failed] => 0
        )
    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1
            [max_score] => 0.19178301
            [hits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => test
                            [_type] => test
                            [_id] => 1
                            [_score] => 0.19178301
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [history.name] => Nicôlàs Wîdàrt
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to set the `ascii_folding` analyzer on all fields ? (not only on history.name)

Comment: I created tried this way, but it is still not ignoring the accented characters.

Comment: Can you paste your query and search results?  What do you mean by "ignoring" the accented characters?

Comment: I have indexed a test item 'Nicôlàs Wîdàrt'. I would like that the search query 'Nicolas', gives me that 'Nicôlàs Wîdàrt' result back. At the moment only a search query **with** the accents are returning the result like 'Nicô' will work.

Comment: Edited the example to be a complete, working demo.  Something else must be wrong with your query or mapping, since the proposed code snippet works.

Comment: Maybe it's the fact that I'm using a wildcard query ? Not a match query. One difference is that I had to apply the `ascii_folding` analyser, manually on every field. http://laravel.io/bin/Del49

Comment: And this is the exact search search: http://laravel.io/bin/PXxW8 (sorry for the format, api call)

Comment: Even with your match query on Sense: https://cloudup.com/cpVHp7aX_QD . Though when specifically searching on the party_name field it works... Still not with the wildcard though.

Comment: [Wildcard queries are `not_analyzed`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html), meaning they won't go through the asciifolding analysis chain that you setup. And re: the match query, did you try without the filter?  It could be the filter that is excluding the docs.  I'm on the road at the moment, but if you can gist up the query (without html :) ) I'll try to make a working demo when I get a chance.

Comment: Ah I see. And is it normal that a `match query` works when looking for the `party_name` field, but not on `_all`? It's the same with a `fuzzy search`. ( I naively tried to specify the analyser on `_all` too, but no change. http://laravel.io/bin/aN5L6 )

Comment: You need to move `_all` definition up one level.  Your snippet has it inside of "properties", but it should be directly under the type declaration. That should make the `_all` behave like the other fields. With the current definition, it's still using the default `standard`, which won't do asciifolding stuff

Comment: Ah okay, I've moved it up one level http://laravel.io/bin/PXeyP. But still either the match or fuzzy query doesn't show the correct result when searching on `_all`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your PHP script is correct (I'm not a PHP dev). I'd may be wrote:

```
$indexParams['body']['settings'][$this->data['index']] = $settings;
```

Comment: When doing this method, in addition to the method explained by @Zach (except for the line `$indexParams['body']['settings'][$this->data['index']] = $settings;`) I get an error when creating the mapping: `MapperParsingException[Analyzer [ascii_folding] not found for field [history.name]`